# How to remove flash of template in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am using filters (of web.xml) to check if the session (http session on server side) is valid or not. If the session is not valid, then the response return error 401, and I handle it in angularjs and redirect the route to login page.

So, the situation is like this:
There is a url localhost:8585/xyz. To access this url, login is required.
When the request is made to access this url (without logging in), the filter check whether the session is valid or not. Meanwhile (as the session is being checked), the template of url localhost:8585/xyz is displayed. As the user is not logged in, session is not valid, so filter send 401 error. I handle the error in angularjs and redirect the route to login page.
I don`t want the template to be displayed before getting the actual response from filters and redirecting the route to login page.

Answer (score 3):

When you're defining your routes you can use the `resolve` property on your route (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider).

This will allow you to specify a function which returns a promise and the route will only be changed once the promise resolves. As an added bonus the value coming back from the resolve promise can be injected into the handling controller.

Here is a **[plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/wJmnFvU5uOrHDdKdoKZo?p=preview)** showing how you can use a global function for any of the routes you need.

Comment: can you tell me how to use the same resolve on all the routes, so that I don't need to write resolve on each route.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ng-cloak`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) to hide flash of unstyled content for Angular if need be.

Your main problem seems to happen after Angular is already loaded, though. In the controller that displays the template you can have a setting:

```
this.loaded = false;
```

Then in the template itself something like:

```
<throbber ng-if=!ctrl.loaded/>
<content ng-if=ctrl.loaded>
    <!-- template content -->
</content>
```

Then you can set `this.loaded = true` when you get the response from the filter.  If you get a 401 the redirect happens anyway and `this.loaded` doesn't get set to true anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Without any example code, it's difficult to know this is possible for you, but the [`ng-show`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) directive can be used to hide an element if it's provided value is falsy:

```
<div ng-show="authenticated">
    <!-- content you wish to hide here -->
</div>
```

In your controller, simply set the value to true when the (successful) response is returned

```
myApp.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.init = function() {
        // check auth here
        $scope.authenticated = true;
    }

    $scope.init();
});
```